# controlling base adapter to change an imageview on click in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am using a base adapter to populate data in listview. I need to change the icon on a click in the adapter class. The problem is I am not getting control of the imageview position in the adapter class. For example if I am using a play/pause icon in a list of music files, I need to change the icon from play to pause of that particular file. Since the control of imageview based on the position in adapter is not getting its pausing/playing a random file. Any help will be mostly appreciated.

**Edit:**

### [Picture of layout used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbIj2.jpg)

I have added a picture of the layout used. Layouts in BaseAdapter has 2 layouts in which one is used to show the sender message and the second is used to show the received one. We are hiding one layout based on the message. Problem here is we are not getting the correct control on the sender/receiver layout. I hope it is clear now.

**Edit 5/21:**

Please find the adapter class and the layout

Adapter

```
package com.app.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.R;
import com.app.handler.DatabaseHandler;
import com.app.materialdesign.CircularImageView;
import com.app.materialdesign.DiscreteSeekBar;
import com.app.model.VoiceMessages;
import com.app.util.PrefManager;
import com.app.util.Utilities;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {


private Context context = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private String location = null;
List<VoiceMessages> voiceMessageList = null;
private DatabaseHandler sqliteHelper = null;
int possitionOfFile = -1;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
private Utilities utils = null;
private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();
private PrefManager pref = null;
private double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
FileInputStream fis;
private ViewHolderItem viewHolder = null;

public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<VoiceMessages> voiceMessageList) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.voiceMessageList = voiceMessageList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return voiceMessageList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_adapter, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.textSeparator = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
    viewHolder.txtReceiveName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtReceiveName);
    viewHolder.txtSendTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSendTime);
    viewHolder.seekBarSender = (DiscreteSeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarSender);
    viewHolder.imgPlaySender = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPlaySender);
    viewHolder.txtSenderName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSenderName);
    viewHolder.txtReceiveTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtReceiveTime);
    viewHolder.txtAudioRemaingreceiverTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAudioRemaingreceiverTime);
    viewHolder.txtAudioRemaingSenderTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAudioRemaingSenderTime);
    viewHolder.dateLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dateLayout);
    viewHolder.senderLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.senderLayout);
    viewHolder.imgPlayReceiver = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayReceiver);
    viewHolder.ProgressLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ProgressLayout);
    viewHolder.receiverMainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receiverMainLayout);
    viewHolder.senderMainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.senderMainLayout);
    viewHolder.ProgressLayoutReceiver = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ProgressLayoutReceiver);
    viewHolder.seekBarReceiver = (DiscreteSeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarReceiver);
    viewHolder.imgViewProefileImag = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgViewProefileImag);
    viewHolder.sendContents = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sendContents);
    viewHolder.senderVoiceIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.senderVoiceIcon);
    viewHolder.receiverContents = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receiverContents);
    viewHolder.receiverVoiceIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.receiverVoiceIcon);
    viewHolder.imgPauseReceiver = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPauseReceiver);
    viewHolder.imgPauseSender = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPauseSender);
    viewHolder.receiverLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receiverLayout);
    possitionOfFile = -1;
    possitionOfFile = position;
    pref = new PrefManager(context);
    utils = new Utilities();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    sqliteHelper = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    if (voiceMessageList.get(position).getDate() != null && !voiceMessageList.get(position).getDate().isEmpty() && voiceMessageList.get(position).getDate().length() > 0) {
        viewHolder.textSeparator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.dateLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.textSeparator.setText(voiceMessageList.get(position).getDate());
    } else {
        viewHolder.dateLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.textSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto-Medium.ttf");

    if (voiceMessageList.get(position).getExchange_action().equalsIgnoreCase("Receive")) {
        if (voiceMessageList.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("False")) {
            viewHolder.imgViewProefileImag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.imgViewProefileImag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        viewHolder.receiverMainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.senderMainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.txtReceiveTime.setText(voiceMessageList.get(position).getCurrentTime().replace("m", "M"));
        viewHolder.txtReceiveName.setText(voiceMessageList.get(position).getUser_display_name());
        location = voiceMessageList.get(position).getVoice_file_path();
        if (voiceMessageList.get(position).getTime_of_recorded_voice().length() == 1) {
            viewHolder.txtAudioRemaingreceiverTime.setText("0:" + "0" + voiceMessageList.get(position).getTime_of_recorded_voice());
        } else {
            viewHolder.txtAudioRemaingreceiverTime.setText("0:" + voiceMessageList.get(position).getTime_of_recorded_voice());
        }

    } else if (voiceMessageList.get(position).getExchange_action().equalsIgnoreCase("Send")) {
        viewHolder.receiverMainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.senderMainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.txtSendTime.setText(voiceMessageList.get(position).getCurrentTime());
        location = voiceMessageList.get(position).getVoice_file_path();
        if (voiceMessageList.get(position).getTime_of_recorded_voice() != null && !voiceMessageList.get(position).getTime_of_recorded_voice().isEmpty()) {
            viewHolder.txtAudioRemaingSenderTime.setText(voiceMessageList.get(position).getTime_of_recorded_voice());
        } else {
            viewHolder.txtAudioRemaingSenderTime.setText("00:00");
        }
    }

    viewHolder.txtSendTime.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    viewHolder.imgPlaySender.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.senderMainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setTag(position);
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                viewHolder.imgPauseSender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.imgPlaySender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.imgPauseSender.requestFocus();
                viewHolder.imgPlaySender.requestFocus();

            } else {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(voiceMessageList.get(position).getVoice_file_path()));
                mediaPlayer.start();
                int clickedPosition = (int) v.getTag();
                viewHolder.imgPauseSender.requestFocus();
                viewHolder.imgPlaySender.requestFocus();
                if (clickedPosition == position) {
                    viewHolder.imgPauseSender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.imgPlaySender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}



@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {
    private TextView textSeparator = null;
    private TextView txtReceiveName = null;
    private TextView txtSendTime = null;
    private DiscreteSeekBar seekBarSender = null;
    private ImageView imgPlaySender = null;
    private TextView txtSenderName = null;
    private TextView txtReceiveTime = null;
    private TextView txtAudioRemaingreceiverTime = null;
    private TextView txtAudioRemaingSenderTime = null;
    private RelativeLayout dateLayout = null;
    private LinearLayout senderLayout = null;
    private ImageView imgPlayReceiver = null;
    private RelativeLayout ProgressLayout = null;
    private LinearLayout receiverMainLayout = null;
    private LinearLayout senderMainLayout = null;
    private RelativeLayout ProgressLayoutReceiver = null;
    private DiscreteSeekBar seekBarReceiver = null;
    private CircularImageView imgViewProefileImag = null;
    private RelativeLayout sendContents = null;
    private ImageView senderVoiceIcon = null;
    private RelativeLayout receiverContents = null;
    private ImageView receiverVoiceIcon = null;
    private ImageView imgPauseReceiver = null;
    private ImageView imgPauseSender = null;
    private LinearLayout receiverLayout = null;
}
}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/senderMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/receiverMainLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/senderDummyImgLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.app.materialdesign.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgViewDummySender"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/attach_contact_pressed"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="#eeeeee"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/senderLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/chat"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4.5">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSenderName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Midhun"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSendTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="4.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="12:30AM"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sendTimeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sendContents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/senderVoiceIcon"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_record_voice_over_white" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ProgressLayout"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/senderVoiceIcon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/senderVoiceIcon"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_white">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgPlaySender"
                    android:layout_width="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play_blue"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgPauseSender"
                    android:layout_width="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/fa_pause"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <com.app.materialdesign.DiscreteSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarSender"
                android:layout_width="153dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ProgressLayout"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ProgressLayout"
                app:dsb_allowTrackClickToDrag="false"
                app:dsb_indicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:dsb_indicatorFormatter="\ %d"
                app:dsb_indicatorTextAppearance="@style/CustomFloaterTextAppearance"
                app:dsb_progressColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:dsb_rippleColor="@color/BlueButton"
                app:dsb_trackColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAudioRemaingSenderTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarSender"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ProgressLayout"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ProgressLayout"
                android:text="0:23"
                android:textColor="@color/VoiceDuration"
                android:textSize="8sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/senderImageLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <com.app.materialdesign.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/senderImgView"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/attach_contact_pressed"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="#eeeeee"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The question is extremely vague and broad, but if I understand what you're after, then you need to write a customer adapter to achieve what you need.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/37301858/2032561

Comment: @AleksG  Sorry If i made it unclear on the question. I have added an image of the layouts used. Please take a look.

Comment: @skadoosh Thanks for the solution. But I think it is not the one required. Already gone through it once.

Comment: post you adapter code. without that cant help..

Comment: @skadoosh posted the code. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you got lot of code and I wrote whatever necessary stuff you need to get your question answered.. mind the code comments

```
    int playingItemPosition=-1;
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        |ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, null);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.receiverMainLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.receiverMainLayout);
            viewHolder.imgPauseSender = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPauseSender);
            //write all findViewById() here
            viewHolder.imgPlaySender = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlaySender);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            //setting listener here
            viewHolder.receiverMainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                    playingItemPosition = pos;//new item clicked and stop o
                    notifyDataSetChanged();//refresh views
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        viewHolder.imgPauseSender.requestFocus();
                        viewHolder.imgPlaySender.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(voiceMessageList.get(playingItemPosition).getVoice_file_path()));
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        viewHolder.imgPauseSender.requestFocus();
                        viewHolder.imgPlaySender.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //check clicked position and change icon accordingly. 
        if (playingItemPosition != -1) {
            if (position == playingItemPosition) {
                viewHolder.imgPauseSender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.imgPlaySender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.imgPauseSender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.imgPlaySender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        //set values to your items 
        viewHolder.receiverMainLayout.setTag(position);


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response and thanks for the answer. We have already tried similar approach and it worked. Although we had other challenges related to the icon click we used similar approach. Thank you once again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTag() and getTag() to get clicked position of item in adapter.

For example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    ImageView ivPlay=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ivPlay.setTag(position); // set position in tag

    ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int clickedPosition = (int) v.getTag(); // get position from tag
            // Here you can perform operation based on position.
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please differentiate between ivPlay and iv?

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: Looking into it. Will keep you posted. Thank you for the help

Comment: If you get the solution from my answer. Please tick as right the answer.

Comment: @SagarZala dont you think according to selected position (which can be only one item playing) you need change image view icons also..

Comment: @SagarZala,@skdoosh. Thank you for the replies. I have added a picture explaining the layouts we are using. Please take a look

Comment: @SagarZala Sorry. Solution you have provided did not work either.

Comment: @SagarZala As you requested I have added the code. Hope this will help you to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Just change some flag on object on this position and call notifyDatasetChanged(). This will invoke redraw of items and then in getView check that flag and draw the image accordingly.
Changing the image directly in imageView will not work if you scroll this item out off screen and back.